# Add all temporary (alias) column results to a TMemo

Tags: mysql, delphi

The goal is to select the first entry from the `DBGrid` (which gives me the `id_employee` value), run the `SQL query` and receive a temporary `column` (`alias`) containing the results.

So far this works. Confirmed by using the `query` in `MySQL Workbench`, it's returning all the values for `column` `total`, for all the `rows` in that `table` that have that specific `id_employee`.

Now I need it to copy all the individual results from the temporary (`alias`) `Result` `column` and paste them into a `TMemo`. After it does that it should move on to the next record in the `DBGrid` and repeat the entire process.

How do I do that? **I've tried using another `for loop` and going through the `Result` field but it doesn't work.**

```
var
row: Integer;
i: Integer;
begin
DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.First;
for row := 0 to DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount -1 do
 begin
 lunaQuery.SQL.Clear;
 lunaQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT total AS Result FROM table1 WHERE id_employee=:id_employee AND Month(date)=:month AND Year(date)=:year';
 lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('id_employee').AsInteger := DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
 lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('month').AsString := ComboBox3.Text;
 lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('year').AsString := Edit3.Text;
 lunaQuery.Open;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(lunaQuery.FieldByName('Result').AsString);

 DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
 end;
end;
```

Pic of results using the above `query` in `MySQL Workbench`: - these need to into the `TMemo`

[image]

I'm using MyDAC components (the query component).

**EDITED:**

It doesn't work though. Only the first `Result` value gets added for each `id_employee` I go through. The potential others for the same `id_employee` aren't added to the `Memo`. I need all `Result` values for each `id_employee` I go through added to the `Memo`.

This is how it looks in the `Memo` after changing to `Query.Open` and running the code above:

[image]

They are correct in the sense that each of them represents only the first value from the `Result` on each `id_employee`. There are more. The `table` contains multiple rows with different total values for each `id_employee`. In Workbench, they successfully show up when I run the query against one `id_employee` but in the `Memo`, because of the loop, only the first one is getting added, while the rest are not.

As you can see by comparing the two pictures - `35` is the first value it finds for `id_employee=1` and adds it to the `Memo` (2nd picture - 1st value). But it's completely ignoring
the next 5 values it finds (pic 1) and moving on adding the first value it finds for the 2nd `id_employee` (`id_employee=2`) which is `20` (pic 2 - 2nd value) then ignoring the other values for `id_employee=2` while moving on the 3rd, adding the first value and so on ...

I'm confused.

Comment: What's wrong with Memo1.Lines.Add?

Comment: `lunaQuery.ExecSQL` is for UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements. Use `lunaQuery.Open`  (or `lunaQuery.Active := True`) to browse the record result of a SELECT statement.

Comment: Other than the wrong use of `ExecSQL` (which is for opertions like `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` and so forth that return no resultset)  insted of using `Open` as @MartynA has pointed out, there isn't any issue with the code you've posted. Just fix that and uncomment the `Memo1.Lines.Add` line.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Oops, thanks for pointing it out. Missed it entirely. Changed now and updated my question as it still isn't working.

Comment: @MartynA Nothing, I'm so confused I switched from Lines.Add to .Text. Changed it back to Lines.Add and put Open vs ExecSQL

Comment: @KenWhite And yet, it still doesn't work properly. I've either explained everything poorly or I'm doing something wrong. I've updated my question with info and the necessary modifications pointed out if you'd care to take another look. Let me know if the question is ambiguous I can try and re-write and explain everything.

Comment: *And yet, it still doesn't work properly* is not helpful. .

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, even after the edit. Does the resultset for lunaQuery return multiple rows for each `i_Employee`? Or is it one result per employee?

Comment: @KenWhite It should return multiple rows for each id_employee, yes. If I run it in workbench using one of the id's it works. If I run it using the code in the question - it only shows one value (the first one it finds) ignoring the rest for that id_employee.

Comment: That's what I thought. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to iterate through the rows of a dataset is a `while not DataSet.Eof` loop.

If your query returns more than one row when it's executed, you also need a loop for that query.

```
begin
  DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.First;
  while not DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.Eof do
  begin
    lunaQuery.SQL.Clear;
    lunaQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT total AS Result FROM table1 WHERE 
    id_employee=:id_employee AND Month(date)=:month AND Year(date)=:year';
    lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('id_employee').AsInteger :=  DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
    lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('month').AsString := ComboBox3.Text;
    lunaQuery.Params.ParamByName('year').AsString := Edit3.Text;
    lunaQuery.Open;

    while not LunaQuery.Eof do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(lunaQuery.FieldByName('Result').AsString);
      lunaQuery.Next;
    end;
    lunaQuery.Close;
    DBGrid4.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank god. Finally. It's been driving me nuts. Tested it and works as intended. I appreciate the help, thank you, and apologies for the ambiguity on my part.

Comment: I'm glad @KenWhite has shown you the correct way to do it.  One of the take-home messages is *never* use a `for` loop on a dataset - use `while not dataset.eof` instead.